# How do I make a control that simulates UpdatePanel but with Jquery AJAX?

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, updatepanel, custom-controls

The question is how do I create a control that simulates an updatepanel?

You're asking me why to hell do I want to that???? It's just pure desire for knowledge :)...

How do I want it to work exactly like UpdatePanel but with totaly my control.

like that:

```
<JQUpdatePanel ID="jqu" runat="server">
 //my html with server controls and other stuff...
</JQUpdatePanel>
```

some scripts and so on.....

Can you suggest how do I begin building some thing like that? 
Because I really don't want to use ScriptManager and real UpdatePanel.

I appreciate any suggestion and thank you in advance.

Comment: The update panel handles a ton of work for you and does a lot of magic with viewstate and everything else.  If you want to support those features you have a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: I have my time and will to develop something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you'd ever really want to do, for learning or otherwise.  UpdatePanel was a very cheap solution, good for very (very) simple scenarios.

If you're wanting to hand-roll some Ajax, then you should take a look at jQuery's Ajax, and com-manipulation APIs.  You would essentially use jQuery (or Prototype, DoJo, etc) to make a call to a web service, then provide a callback that uses the service result to update your dom.

There are many tutorials online that will get you started.

Comment: That's not what i've asked for!!!
I use jquery for more than a year in my working apps, i want to do the thing i have asked for.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that UpdatePanel has a lot of plumbing that does exotic things with the ViewState.  Re-implementing this is a monumental undertaking, and not something someone is going to be able to help you with in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Why not?! I'm trying ti understand what's going on in the UpdatePanel Control.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom control that inherits the UpdatePanel and then injects the calls to jquery instead of injecting the ajax calls.

Comment: Didn't got your explanation, could you please explain your self a little better.